# C# - Separate project into 2 seperate projects by dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, dependencies, projects-and-solutions

I have project A and project B.
Project A use project B dll.

I want to get all the dependencies of project A out from project B and separate them into 2 different projects, project B and project C.

I want project A to use only project C.

The dependency been declared by class's(in properties, interfaces, methods body , interfaces, methods parameters, base class, attribute etc.).

Is there some way or tool to do it?
If not is there some known methodology for this mission?

Comment: Someone? I really need your help in that matter...

Comment: IMHO, no tool is available.
You will need to do it manually.

Comment: I implemented a tool that does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation I found out that there is not such a tool.
In the end I implement a tool that does it by set a dictionary of dependencies for each type(including class, enum, methods interface, method body, properties, class members, attribute etc.)

Comment: It would be nice you post it on github.